# Unicode project for CString to const byte*?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode

can someone help me to convert CString to const byte pointer.  I try below code, but it does not work.  My program uses Unicode setting.

```
Cstring hello = "MyApp";
const BYTE* pData = (const BYTE*)(LPCTSTR)hello;
```

thanks.

Comment: Do you want bytes that represent the string in your local code page or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [How to convert CString to BYTE pointer](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/VC-MFC/30629369/how-to-convert-cstring-to-byte-pointer.aspx):

- interpret it as ascii string:

  ```
  CStringA asciiString( hello );
  const BYTE* lpData = (const BYTE*)(LPCSTR)asciiString;
  ```
- *or* convert to bytes that represent the string in your local code page:

  ```
  CT2CA buf( hello );
  const BYTE* lpData = (const BYTE*)buf;
  ```

Comment: What is the different between CString and CStringA?

Comment: Thanks it works.  I use the first suggestion.  But any idea why when I call this RegSetValueEx(hKey,Path, NULL, REG_SZ, pData, sizeof(pData));, it does not write "MyApp" to registry.

Comment: @Lufia: the difference `CString` vs `CStringA` is the same as for `_T("abc")` vs. `"abc"` i.e., `TCHAR` vs. ANSI strings. `sizeof(pData)` is `sizeof(pointer)` but you need length of `pData` in bytes (including the zero byte at the end).

Answer (score 0):

Try (PCWSTR)

document is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a994dfk(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to understand if you are using unicode or not. By default Visual studio likes to make apps so they are using Unicode. If what you are wanting is ANSI (which only uses 1 byte per letter), you will need to convert it from Unicode to ANSI. This will give you the BYTE* to the object. Here is a way to do it:

```
    CString hello;
    hello=L"MyApp"; // Unicode string

int iChars = WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8,0,(LPCWSTR) hello,-1,NULL,0,NULL,NULL); // First we need to get the number of characters in the Unicode string
if (iChars == 0) 
    return 0; // There are no characters here.

BYTE* lpBuff = new BYTE[iChars];  // alocate the buffer with the number of characters found
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8,0,(LPCWSTR) hello,-1,(LPSTR) lpBuff,iChars-1, NULL, NULL); // And convert the Unicode to ANSI, then put the result in our buffer.
```

// And if you want to have it a constant byte pointer just add this line:

```
    const BYTE* cbOut = lpBuff;
```

Now if all you want is to access the CString as whatever it is natively, then just cast it as:

```
    const TCHAR* MyString = (LPCTSTR) hello;
```